# powershell tts command narrator change using python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, text-to-speech

Does anyone know how to change the voice in this tts powershell command?

```
-Powershell Command Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech
$Speaker = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$Speaker.Speak('oh my god, I can now talk; it''s amazing!')
```

And it needs to be as small as possible as I'm implementing this using pythons os.system() command

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx): it's easily possible.

Answer (score 3):

A quick translation of a script in my repo:

```
## SelVoiceSpeak.ps1
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Speech"
$speaker = new-object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speaker.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice()
write-host "These voices are installed:`r`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
$cntr = 0;
$voices = $speaker.GetInstalledVoices() | Where Enabled | ForEach VoiceInfo
$voices | %{$cntr++;write-host "[$cntr] $($_.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green}
$choice = Read-Host "`r`nChoose a name [1-$($voices.length)]"
if ($choice -gt 0 -and $choice -le $voices.length){
    $voice = $voices[$choice -1].Name
    $speaker.SelectVoice($voice)
} else {
    write-Host "no valid choice" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
}
$text = Read-Host "`r`nEnter text to speak"
write-host "`r`nspeaking now!" -BackgroundColor DarkCyan -ForegroundColor White
$speaker.Speak($text)
```

Quite ugly colors, sample output:

```
> .\SelVoiceSpeak.ps1
These voices are installed:

[1] Microsoft Hedda Desktop
[2] Microsoft Zira Desktop

Choose a name [1-2]: 2

Enter text to speak: hello world!

speaking now!
```

**EDIT: A minimal script without any checking,**
speaking a fixed voice and a fixed text, could be concatenated with ';' to a single line:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Speech"
$speaker = new-object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speaker.SelectVoice("Microsoft David Desktop")
$speaker.Speak("This is a text")
```

Comment: Just a pro-tip, there are two parameter sets for `ForEach-Object` (`%`).  One will automatically enumerate members so `| % { $_.Property }` is unnecessary: `| % Property`.  The same is true of `Where-Object` (`?`) where it can implicitly do things without the `filterscript`: `| ? {$_.Enabled}` becomes `| ? Enabled`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That was a quite old script, I just translated from German, I'd write it differently today.

Comment: Even so, I wanted to point those things out for anyone else that looks at it because it's common people will keep doing things the way they always have without knowing there are new features that make their code more efficient, or at the very least, easier to read / digest.

Comment: LotPings do you have a simpler command or one that one line its just i'm executing this using pythons os.system() command

Comment: How do you want to select the voice? By a fixed name? See the edited answer.

Comment: Just a simple argument or a list of names ?

Comment: My idea is to store a voice in a variable and then use it in each tts command. I've found out how to do this with text but not voice

Comment: My script shows how to list installeed voices, to select you need just to pass the complete name like `Microsoft David Desktop` or whatever the script lists on **your** computer